# In Firefox, focus on "Search the Web" bar in new tabs

Tags: firefox, browser, search, tabs, address-bar

How can I have the cursor automatically focused onto the "Search the Web" bar in new tabs, in Firefox 57? This box appears in the middle of the page of new tabs.

Right now, when I open a new tab, the address bar is in focus instead. I have to hit Tab three times to focus on the search box instead.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this one out in FF 67. I know the address bar is functionally the same as the search bar, but I prefer inputting searches in the middle of the page where it's more visible. I tried every possible value of accessibilty.tabfocus in about:config, where 1=give focus to text fields only, 2=give focus to all form elements except text fields, 4=give focus to links (and linked images) only, as well as each combination of these three, and still no luck.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this one out in FF100.